# What are the advantages of TNS?

Tags: oracle, tns

I'm new to Oracle database and I don't understand what we're gaining when we use TNS? Why not use plain TCP/IP?

As far as I understood, TNS is additional network layer. But I don't understand what it does. Wikipedia states:

> supports homogeneous peer-to-peer connectivity

Does TCP/IP support it also?

I'm actually surprised that there is so little information about this on the Internet.

Comment: TNS is using TCP: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/application-and-networking-architecture.html#GUID-94AFB4A0-4979-4B48-A19A-0D9178771FB1

Comment: what do you think TNS means/does?

Comment: TNS is more akin to DNS than to TCP/IP.

Comment: TNS is low level proprietary protocol over TCP IP or IPC to allow Oracle to encode various datatypes or messages between server and client. Think of it as it was something like ASN + BER/DER. Since it is undocumented and proprietary it does not have any use outside Oracle platform.

Comment: Also,  I think TNS was in use before TCP/IP was the only game in town. So it would abstract away over the various network protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People often use "TNS" to refer to *TNS Names* (or *Local Naming*), which is an optional, shorthand way of specifying your database connection information. [You put your TCP/IP connection information in your **tnsnames.ora** file](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260) with a nickname like "MYSERVER", and then you can just `connect MYSERVER` without providing the hostname/port/service-name every time.

TNSNames.ora example:

```
MYSERVER= 
 (DESCRIPTION=  
  (ADDRESS= 
     (PROTOCOL=tcp) 
     (HOST=192.168.1.17) 
     (PORT=1521)) 
  (CONNECT_DATA=  
     (SERVICE_NAME=myservice)))
```

You'll notice that it has an IP address right there, and says "PROTOCOL=tcp".

Connecting with TNSNames:

```
sqlplus user@MYSERVER
```

But you don't have to use the TNS Names shortcut if you don't want to - [connect strings support a number of different naming methods](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetservices-neteasyconnect-133058.pdf).

Connecting with EZCONNECT syntax:

```
sqlplus user@\"192.168.1.17:1521/myservice\"
```

But finally, TNSNames is a small part of the picture. As the commenters mentioned above, "TNS" is more accurately used to refer to the [proprietary session layer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/architecture.htm#i1044193) component of the *Oracle Net foundation layer* used to communicate with any Oracle database. You can't connect to an Oracle database without using TNS.

Comment: Apart from `tnsnames.ora` file you can provide TNS name resolution also by a name server which uses the LDAP protocol, similar to an DNS name server.